# Best approach to implement API for user space clients

Tags: sockets, system-calls

I need to develop an interface which user space clients can invoke to access the kernel methods I already have implemented. I know of the following two approaches with their pros/cons to achieve this.

1. Introduce a system call

   - Pros: Simple, For different kernel methods, different argument can be passed.
   - Cons:  Any side effect ?
2. Introduce a new family of socket and use IOCTL commands

   - Pros: No need of API explanations. Everybody knows how to use sockets
   - Cons: time consuming to implement.

Are there any other advantage/disadvantages of these two approaches that can be weighed in to decide one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a user-mode library that exports good old functions, then implement the user/kernel interface inside the library any way you want. But it is *very important* that the direct kernel interface not be public. End user support would be a nightmare.

I prefer IOCTL calls to a device driver. Very flexible, very little overhead. But not user-friendly.